# Не срабатывает onDestroy

Tags: java, android

Имеется активити, в которой в `onCreate` вызываю фрагмент видео плеера. Во фрагменте есть методы:

```
 @Override
  public void onResume() {
    onResume();
    //Воспроизвел видео
  }

 @Override
 public void onPause() {
  onPause();
  //Остановил видео
 }
```

Далее есть такие программы по освобождению ОП. Например диспетчер задач. Нажал я остановить процесс, остановил, но `onDestroy` ни в активити ни во фрагменте не срабатывает. Соответственно, получается запускаю снова программу, и сначала идет старый фрагмент, а снизу него новый, и видео начинают играть два. Ссылка на старый плеер уже утеряна. Как сделать так, чтобы onDestroy работал?

Answer (score 3):

Никак. Вызов метода [`onDestroy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) не гарантирован. Перестраивайте логику приложения.

Comment: А как тогда быть если все не освободится то будет утечка памяти.Есть идеи как перестроить?

Comment: Попробуйте делать это в onStop() http://www.fandroid.info/ostanovka-i-perezapusk-deyatelnosti/   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onstop

Comment: В onStop пробовал ругается мол после saverinstance нельзя удалить фрагмент.В onCreate активити я фрагмент добавляю как add, но если использовать replace то все ок.Вот не будетли это ошибкой и не привидет ли у утечкам всяким?

Comment: @Ivan Не будет. методом `add()` вы добавляете в контейнер еще один фрагмент. Методом `replace()` - заменяете один фрагмент другим. Выполнение метода `onStop()` так же не гарантировано системой. Последний (и первый) гарантированный метод закрытия - `onPause()`

Comment: Тогда replace и система предыдущий фрагмент освободит сама.